# issue with decoding json from database field, getting Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

trying to decode a field from a database that contains json code relating to uploaded images.

My code below shows the content of the database field as the variable $fulljson. If I comment that line out and un-comment  the line above it, I get the error 
"Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

When I use the code copied from the database and directly in the page (as below) then the code works. The only thing I can see different is that the code in the database field is not enclosed by ''

Can anybody tell me what I have done wrong?

```
//$fulljson = $Recordset1->getColumnVal("OTHER_IMAGES");
$fulljson = '[{"name":"..\/info_images\/busy_ez13vu9n.jpg","usrName":"busy.jpg","size":165287,"type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail":"..\/info_images\/thbusy_fp6vtpk5.jpg","thumbnail_type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail_size":40250,"searchStr":"busy.jpg,!soap.jpg,!jewelry.jpg,!dolls.jpg,!:sStrEnd"},{"name":"..\/info_images\/soap_ejlj7tyb.jpg","usrName":"soap.jpg","size":105446,"type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail":"..\/info_images\/thsoap_armbl621.jpg","thumbnail_type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail_size":38678},{"name":"..\/info_images\/jewelry_aa4w7kcz.jpg","usrName":"jewelry.jpg","size":129071,"type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail":"..\/info_images\/thjewelry_0php731c.jpg","thumbnail_type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail_size":36068},{"name":"..\/info_images\/dolls_050jmi5d.jpg","usrName":"dolls.jpg","size":91500,"type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail":"..\/info_images\/thdolls_p8t25nyl.jpg","thumbnail_type":"image\/jpeg","thumbnail_size":34218}]';
$someJSON = $fulljson;

$someArray = json_decode($someJSON, true);

foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "<div class=\"col-md-4\" style=\"margin-bottom: 5px\" ><a href=\"" . $value["name"] . "\" class=\"fancybox img-hover-v2\"><span><img src=\"" . $value["thumbnail"] . "\" class=\"img-fluid\"></span></a> </div>";
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are getting a different result from the databse than you think. What does `var_export($fulljson)`; print if you put it directly after the first line (and comment it in)?

Comment: @ArSeN you are right, it seems to truncate the last part of the contents. I tried to reduce the size of the content, but it truncated at the exact same point (content ends with :"image\/jpeg","thumbnail_size":38678}], but the query is ending at "image\/jpeg"," even when I took some data off)  i talked with the web host, they said my script was incorrect, and I don;t know enough to argue with them